# shell bad subsitution error retrieving jenkins env variables

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, amazon-eks

I am trying to use a jenkins env variable within my shell script but getting "bad subsitution error "

shellscript

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#Set Parameters

"echo \"from shell i=${env.abc}\""
echo \"test test="${env.abc}"\"
echo "${env.abc}"
```

I have tried to retrieve the values for jenkins environment variable abc in my shell script through all above ways. It gives me "bad substitution" error

This variable is being generate runtime in jenkins pipeline and is being set to jenkins env variable at runtime.

jenkins file:

```
pipeline {
    agent { node { label 'pqr' } }
    stages {
        stage( 'stage1') {
            steps {
                script {
                   withEnv(["address=https://xxxxxxxxxx.com"]) {
                        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'xxxxxxxx', usernameVariable: 'id', passwordVariable: 'password')]) {
                        
                            abc_original = sh (
                                script: "*************").trim()
                            sh "echo ${abc_original}"

                    withEnv(["abc=${abc_original}"])  {
                    thisPipeline.callpipelinemethod()
                    sh "echo ${env.abc_original}"
//                    }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to fetch the abc_original value through jenkins script but unable to retrieve this value in the shell script.

can someone help?

Comment: In the shell, environment variable are simply referred to by name: `echo "$abc"`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `returnStdout: true` option in your sh call.

It should look like,

```
         abc_original = sh (
           script: "*************",
           returnStdout: true
         ).trim()
```